# Function that returns char *

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a function that receives an `int` and returns a pointer to a string array:

```
char* DoSomething (int num);
```

But I don't understand how to deal with it in the main. Essentially I want to print the string I am getting from the function.
But in the main I get a warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type.
This is my main:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 12345;
    char* a;
    a = DoSomething(12345);
    return 0;
}
```

Updating. I didn't want to put a long code, but adding as per your request.
The function is defined in a separate c file.

```
/* conver int to String */
char* IntToString (int num)
{
    int i;
    int sign = 1;
    int len;
    int begin = 0;
    char* str = malloc (sizeof(char)*30);  
    if (num<0)
    {
        sign = -1;
        num = num*(-1);
    }
    len = CountDigits(num);
    if (sign == -1)
    {
        str[0]='-'; 
        begin = 1;
    }
    int newLen = len;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        int digit;
        char digitChar;
        int modul;

        digit = num/(pow(10, newLen-1));
        digitChar = digit + ASCII_ZERO;
        str[i+begin] = digitChar;
        modul = pow(10, newLen-1);
        num = num % modul;
        newLen--;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Then in the main I am trying to call the function:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 12345;
    char* a;
    a = IntToString(12345);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of `DoSomething` function?

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the necessary include statements for the needed header file.

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and in the parameter to `malloc()` just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: the posted code, even after the edits, is missing the definition of the function: `countdigits()`

Comment: could save a lot of hassle by using: `memset( str, '\0', 30 ); for( int i=0; num; i++)  {  str[i] = num%10; num -= digit; }`

Answer (score 4):

You get a warning because the function is defined after `main`, and lacks prototype.

Move the function to before `main`, or add this line:

```
char* DoSomething (int num);
```

Now the warning will be gone, and you would be able to print your string in a way that you prefer, for example

```
printf("%s\n", a);
```

**Note 1:** The string you are returning is not null terminated.

**Note 2:** Since you are using `malloc` in the function, you need to call `free` on the result in the `main`.

Comment: Just a suggestion, include stdlib.h too